# Handling URL parameters in routing for search keywords in terms of best practise and security

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Routing below is searching purposes so the URL will have keywords to go with. What I need to know is to define `keyword` in a way that it is secure? How can I do it in yml? We all know that keyword entered by user can contain anything!

*Note*: I can ignore it doing in yml below and handle it in controller but I want to know how could it be done in yml as well.

Thanks in advance

**ROUTING.YML**

```
search_result:
    pattern:  /search/result/{field}/{keyword}
    defaults: { _controller: CarBrandBundle:Search:result }
    methods:  [GET]
    requirements:
        field:  brands|cars|both
        keyword:  ??????????????????????????
```

I've checked [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) guide but nothing specific there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a regular expression, limiting the input to the specified pattern. In fact, your `requirements.field` is a regex already.

You should however know that, if the input doesn't match the pattern, there will not be an exception, but the route simply will not be considered matching. Therefore it may be better to catch all and do the actual handling in the controller.

Comment: How would you specify regex for the `keyword` parameter? Any example cos I cannot find any for my specific purpose.

Comment: You can simply pass a PCRE regex, without delimiters and modifiers. I don't know what exactly you need, could you please describe what would be valid values for the *keyword* parameter?

Comment: In simple words, anything is legal unless it is some sort of script which may be used to exploit the website like XSS, javascript etc. Since keyword field is a text field in web form, everyone is free to enter whatever they want and what they entered is then used in controller to generate the URL. I could do all that in controller itself but just wondering if the router can be useful or not before the request hits the controller.

Comment: OK this is the scenario: you're a bad guy and entering some sort of JS  or a XSS stuff in keyword text field in search form and submit it. Controller then picks your request and creates an URL with using your malicious keywords. I want to eliminate such bad keywords in routing if possible before hitting the controller. I can easily handle it controller but that's not the point for now.

Comment: Then simply use `.*`, and do proper filtering in the controller.

Comment: It is impossible to construct a regex that filters out all possibly malicious entries. If the keyword parameter is a search query, simply escape it properly or use a prepared statement, and you should be fine. But I would never embed it back into the webpage ("your search results for *foo*"), if you're not applying very strict validitation.